# Parseval's Theorem to estimate number of terms

Tags: calculus, integration

> Question:
>   Find the Fourier series for $f (x) = x^2$ on the range $(−\pi, \pi)$.
>
> Use Parseval’s theorem to estimate approximately how many terms of the Fourier
>   series are required to be summed to give a typical error of 0.1 on $f(x)$.

Solution so far:
I have calculated $S(x)= (π^2)/6 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n (4/(n^2) \cos(nx)$

How do I proceed?